# How can I change the billing frequency in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, billing

I want to change the billing frequency in my Firebase account to Annually or something else? However, there is no way to change it.
[image: Screenshot that shows 'How to pay' in Firebase]

Can someone help, please?

Comment: I'm not certain if there are alternatives here, but if there are the best way to learn more about them is to [reach out to support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/account-services/).

Comment: Raised a ticket in Firebase Support. Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746)

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

Firebase subscriptions are charged monthly. There are no other options available at the moment.

Comment: Sad to know :( Do you know if there is any plan to add more options under it and when?

Comment: If this feature would be useful to you, I recommend you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).